# Find number of ways in which $5$ distinct balls can be placed into $3$ distinct boxes.

Tags: combinatorics

> Find number of ways in which $5$ distinct balls can be placed into $3$ distinct boxes

When I tried this in a way like I can distribute $5$ balls can be placed into first box, then $4$ in next and remaining $3$ in the last box.  Now I got the answer as $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3$.  But the given answer is $3^5$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You're looking at it the wrong way round - you should consider each ball having $3$ options for the bin it is placed in which gives $3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3=3^5$ possible combinations

Comment: @lioness99a can you please say why we can't go this way.

Comment: @abvr1018 Because the problem as stated supposes that you could put all five balls into the first box. Or the first two balls in the last box and the other three in the second box. What it does _not_ suppose is that you can just put only three of the balls in boxes and the other two stay somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you are a ball and you have 3 boxes infront of you. You want to choose any one box of your wish. There are three boxes, so there are 3 possibilities for a single ball. There are five balls so we have
3.3.3.3.3=243 posibillities.
Remember that there may any number of balls in a single box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that you are putting one ball into each box and getting an incorrect answer.

In fact, think about it this way: for each ball, you can choose a box you will put it in.

Comment: Thanks for clarification of my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

How many possibilities are there for the first ball? How many for the second one?

For each unique choice for the first ball do you have a unique choice for the second one?

Hope this helped